# Do you leave the oven thermometer inside the oven while you are baking?

Tags: baking, oven, thermometer

We have a very old gas oven at home. I just started baking but every time I use it for baking, I end up having burnt cookies, unevenly baked cakes, etc. 
I plan on buying an oven thermometer. I'd like to know if I should leave the thermometer inside the oven in order to  monitor the temperature. Or should I take it out once the oven has been preheated enough?

Answer (score 5):

In your case it's definitely worth leaving it in, because it will help you get to the bottom of whether things are burning because the temperature keeps rising during cooking.

Oven thermometers are generally designed so that they can be left in. I prefer the type that can hang from a rack

Comment: Yes, leave it in the oven all the time. But, if your oven has a self-cleaning cycle, remove it before initiating that. My oven's temperture during the self-cleaning cycle exceeds what the thermometer can withstand and it will be ruined. Made that mistake only once (so far)

Comment: @Cynetta you have a self-cleaning gas oven?

Comment: @Fabby Yes, my gas range has a self-cleaning oven feature

Comment: Wow!  I wish I would have known about this before I bought my oven!  (Note to self: remember to ask @Cynetta in 15 years which oven to buy!  **;-)** )

Comment: I have an over thermometer which hangouts inside the oven all the time :)